# Rename Google Maps Advanced Marker View tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The Google Maps *Advanced Marker View* has been renamed to [Advanced Marker Element](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/advanced-markers).

We have the corresponding tag: [google-maps-advanced-marker-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-advanced-marker-view)

Could we rename this to reflect the new naming?

I would suggest using [google-maps-advanced-marker-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-advanced-marker-element).

Comment: There are only 6 questions.  Is this tag really needed at all?  Don't all the other `google-maps*` tags cover it?

Comment: @toolic it's a new feature that was in beta until May 4. It's the future of Google Maps Markers.

Comment: @toolic If the tag should exist is a different issue than the name of the tag. If the tag is to exist, then it should have the official name, particularly when the rename was something that happened between beta and release and/or early in the thing's history.